# header location doesn't work inside the if statement

Tags: php

> I made a login form when the credentials are right it will go to another page but it displays an empty page instead.

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT username as username, password as password
                from tbl_users
                where user_type ='system admin'";
    $result= sqlsrv_query($db,$query);

    while ($user=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $uname = $user['username'];
        $pwd = $user['password'];
    }

        // $url = 'http://localhost/chart/e/home.php';
        if ($username == $uname && $password == $pwd ) {
            header('Location : http://localhost/chart/e/home.php');
            exit;
        }

        else{
            echo "<script> alert('error') </script>";
        }

}
```

> here's the form

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="text" placeholder ="username" name="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder ="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Sign in">
</form>
```

Comment: can you post your full php code ?

Comment: also provide error log if any

Comment: try like this    header('Location :home.php');

Comment: I updated my code

Comment: ('Location: home.php') also didn't work

Comment: then un comment variable $url ...and try to pass the $url in header..use exit();

Comment: that also didn't work.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but do not store passwords in plain text. Take a look at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.

Comment: You've got completely incorrect logic (selecting all users and then pointlessly looping over them and overwriting variables), look up some tutorials.

Comment: @hikarisakunami break your while loop when your credentials becomes true using flag variable. refer this updated code.

$flag = 0;
while ($user=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $uname = $user['username'];
        $pwd = $user['password'];
        if ($username == $uname && $password == $pwd ) { $flag = 1; }
}
 // $url = 'http://localhost/chart/e/home.php';
if ($flag == 1) {
     header('Location:http://localhost/chart/e/home.php');
     exit;
} else{
     echo "<script> alert('error') </script>";
}

Hope it helps.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the whitespace between header field (`Location`) and colon (`:`):

```
header('Location: http://localhost/chart/e/home.php');
```

> Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names are case-insensitive. The field value MAY be preceded by any amount of LWS, though a single SP is preferred.

For reference, see:

- http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html

Answer (score -1):

if (($username == $uname) && ($password == $pwd )) {$url = "http://localhost/chart/e/home.php";
     header('Location : '.$url);exit;
}

Comment: you can print both variable $username, $uname, $password and $pwd, values proper comes then you can give else part and check again.

Comment: This answer won't even begin to solve this users problem.

Comment: <?php if(isset($_POST['login'])){ $username = $_POST['username']; $password = $_POST['password']; $uname = 'pk'; $pwd = 'kk'; if ($username == $uname && $password == $pwd ) { echo "etst";exit; header('Location : index.php'); exit; } else{ echo "crax";exit; echo "<script> alert('error') </script>"; } } ?> <form method="POST"> <input type="text" class="text" placeholder ="username" name="username"> <input type="password" placeholder ="password" name="password"> <input type="submit" name="login" value="Sign in"> </form>

Comment: try with above code its working and put your dynamic value of db in :

Comment: $uname = 'pk';
$pwd = 'kk';